# NativeScript can't find Android SDK on Mac OS

Tags: android, macos, nativescript, android-sdk-tools, angular2-nativescript

I've installed NativeScript and I try to do `tns platform add android` but it doesn't work. ANDROID_HOME path is correct and I have installed SDK (API 22 and the newest one) and tools (25.0.2). When I run `tns doctor` it says:

```
WARNING: The Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.
Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 22 or later.

You need to have the Android SDK Build-tools installed on your system. You can install any version in the following range: '>=25.0.2'.

You need to have Android SDK 22 or later and the latest Android Support Repository installed on your system.
```

Comment: Please check out https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2583#issuecomment-285477270 - you could redownload the android Sdk and download an earlier version of platform-tools to temporarily workaround this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current version of NativeScript 2.5.2 requires certain tools to be in the Android home directory so that it can detect them.   The newest version of Android SDK (Mar 2017) actually removed the primary `android` support file and moved several binary files into other directories to clean things up.

Unfortunately this causes NativeScript to not be able to detect that you have the SDK.  This version of the SDK came out AFTER the current version of NativeScript.

The simplest way to fix this that I can think of is to start from the command line; `sdkmanager` then choose to download the older 25.2.3 tools.

To manually do this; you would need to delete everything in your `sdk/tools` folder and download:

> https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip (Windows) 
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip  (Macintosh)
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip    (Linux)

Then extract these into that `sdk/tools` directory.

Comment: Hmm now I have error:
`Command npm failed with exit code 243`
But Android try to install. So it is one step closer to success.

Comment: I deleted my tools directory and downloaded/unzipped the windows zip. Running tns doctor still yields:  Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 22 or later.
Run $ %ANDROID_HOME%\tools\android to manage your Android SDK versions.

You need to have Android SDK 22 or later and the latest Android Support Repository installed on your system.
Run $ %ANDROID_HOME%\tools\android to manage the Android Support Repository.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this using the SDK manager in Android Studio, having already installed it previously, install all the requirements, namely

```
tools,platform-tools,android-25,build-tools-25.0.2,extra-android-m2repository,extra-google-m2repository,extra-android-support
```

Once installed change your ANDROID_HOME environment variable to point to this SDK manager. Typically, it will be at (/Users//Library/Android/sdk)

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/<user_name>/Library/Android/sdk
```

Confirm that NativeScript detects your changes by running

```
tns doctor
```